How to find which User created a Database View in an Oracle Database?
I need to determine who created a view in an Oracle Database. I do not have access to the database myself, so I am looking for a query to provide. I believe the equivalent for a TSQL database is
Select p.name, v.*
FROM sys.all_views v
JOIN sys.database_principals p ON p.principal_id = v.schema_id
WHERE v.name = 'name of view'

I believe sys.database_principals equivalent is USER for an Oracle DB, but I am still looking into the rest of these, and how I will have to modify my query.

SELECT owner, created
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_name = 'your_view_name'
AND object_type = 'VIEW';
Would this work?

Hi , you can use all_views view also ,   Select  v.owner, v.*
FROM sys.all_views v

You'd have to find it in the audit trail, assuming DDL is being audited. Nothing in the dictionary is going to store who created it, only which schema owns it.

If you want to find out who OWNS the view then you can use:
SELECT owner
FROM   all_views
WHERE  view_name = 'YOUR_VIEW'

or:
SELECT owner
FROM   all_objects
WHERE  object_name = 'YOUR_VIEW'
AND    object_type = 'VIEW'

Note: unless you are using quoted identifiers (which is considered bad practice) then the name of the view will be upper-case.
However, the data dictionary does not tell you which user CREATED the view (which does not have to be the owner). For that you would need to have enabled auditing on the database and then you could query the audit trail.
